# Передача изображения из view в action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здраствуйте.
У меня есть view  в которой находиться img.Его я заполняю с проперти модели    public byte[] Photo {get;set;} .Когда я делаю пост, я передаю свою модель в другой екшн, какой обработивает пост-запросы,и чтоб передать изображение, я передаю его хайден инпуте    [@Html](/users/14007/htmlplus).HiddenFor(m => m.Photo) .Наверное, ето не очень хорошо.Можна ли передать имидж в екшн как-то по другому.
Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы уже перед выводом на вьюху имеете массив байт для фото то почему бы не сохранить его пока на диск во временную папку и передавать просто путь к фото ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Идея вообще интересная.
Есть ли возможность загрузить імидж и сразу его отрендерить, без постбека?Я думал ето зделать Ajax запросом, но, как пишут, єто невозможно.Есть какой-либо другой способ?